# How to properly rename all variables in syntax tree

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I am trying to "protect" my code (Test.cs) with obfuscating. I got all (values, classes, etc) from my file

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(file);
var methods = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
var variables = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<VariableDeclarationSyntax>();
var parameters = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ParameterSyntax>();
var classes = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
```

but now i don't know how to properly rename them. I tried to use `string.Replace()` and `Regex` to replace values manually, but there are a lot of incorrect replacing (for example same text in brackets, etc). 
How i can done that properly

Comment: Trying to understand what your goal is; are you sure obfuscation is the right way to go? Usually people just compile their source code and share the binary instead of the code, which is obfuscation enough. And if not then there are tools like Dotfuscator or SmartAssembly that make it harder to decompile your stuff.

Comment: Good obfuscators don't just rename methods, they rename local variables, add code calls that result in completely useless classes and calls (that are optimized out at runtime) and other things. Unless your goal is to write an obfuscator, I'd use a commercially available tool instead of trying to roll your own. Just renaming the classes/methods is a pretty weak obfuscation method.

Comment: @Longoon12000 yes, but i will replace my variables to like ```private object aFEWeqwfe(wqfwWQ ewf)
        {```

Comment: @RonBeyer i am not trying to do hard obfuscation, just simple things like renaming